# Overloading operator = in c++

Tags: c++

In the code below, I don't get what "this" is (not the keyword, but what it points to). Is "this" is reference or pointer to current object?

And when checking a=a assign `if(this!=&a)` , why "this" is compared with &a, and not with a?

The class Book have private member `*num_pages` that points to number of pages in the book.

```
Book &Book::operator=(const Book& a){
    if(this!=&a){
        delete num_pages;
        num_pages = new int;
        *num_pages = *a.num_pages;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Why do you not have simply a class member `int num_pages;` instead of the `int* num_pages;`?

Comment: This is just example that we got on college for demonstrating copy constructor and overloading operators..

Comment: Which introductory C++ book are you reading that does *not* cover this?

Comment: This is just a stupid example then, because everyone would reasonably do what I mentioned, and so the whole construct boils down to `num_pages = a.num_pages; return *this;`

Comment: I read some book from Laslo Kraus, and it does cover all about this, but i just wanted to be 100% clear about this stuff.

Comment: @bliny: How can you be confused about whether `this` is a pointer or a reference? If a book gets that wrong, toss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example above `this` is a pointer to the object on the left hand side of the assignment operator. For example, if you write the code below

```
Book b1, b2;
b1 = b2;
```

then inside your operator `=` `this` is the address of `b1`, and `a` is `b2`.

> why `this` is compared with `&a`, and not with `a`?

Because `this` represents a pointer to `Book`, while `a` represents a constant reference to `Book`. In order to compare the two, their level of indirection must be the same (both must be pointers). This is done so that a valid self-assignment

```
b1 = b1;
```

would not cause problems.

Comment: May help to explain that we want `operator=` to also work for the case where we do `b1 = b1;`, where `this == &a` since `a = b1, and `this = &b1`.

Comment: Suggestion: "inside your `operator=`, `this` is the address of `b1` and `a` is `b2`." (Omitting the tedious "value of"; more precisely it should of course be "the value of `this`" and "the value of `a`".)

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks! That's much cleaner than what I wrote.

Comment: Thanks man. Just one more thing. the `&` in the `Book &Book::operator=(const Book& a)` means that the function in returning reference right? So if we are returning `*this`, why the type of function isn't just pointer `*`?

Comment: @bliny Correct, the first `&` means that the operator returns a reference (hence the asterisk in `return *this`). Return type is not a pointer so that you could have a value-like semantic: when you write `b1 = b2` you treat a book like an object, not like a pointer, so the language reflects that.

Answer (score 1):

this is a pointer. It is compared with the address of a to avoid self-assignment.

Comment: Which would lead to happy times in this very example.